# Tile Package made with ArcPy are not tiling all layers or levels of detail

Tags: arcpy

I'm having a weird issue with CreateMapTilePackage_management in ArcPy. The tile packages that are created by this tool do not have all layers and levels of detail. I'm not sure what is causing this. Even the tiles look off when put into arcmap.

Has anyone ever seen this?

Here is the code example:

```
 df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(map_document, "Road_Map")
 for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(map_document, "", df):
    if lyr.name == "Conductor":
       print "\n\n**** FOUND THE CORRECT MAP LAYER ****\n\n"
       time.sleep(3)
       print "\n\n**** SETTING UP ARCGIS WORK ENVIRONMENT ***\n\n"
       arcpy.env.workspace = loc_of_featureclasses 
       for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():
            print "\n\n**** CHANGING LAYER DATA SOURCE ****\n\n"
            lyr.replaceDataSource(loc_of_featureclasses, "FILEGDB_WORKSPACE", fc, True)
            map_document.save()
            print ("\n\n**** ZOOMING TO LAYER EXTENT ****\n\n")
            dataFrame = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(map_document)[0] # the first data frame
            MapLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(map_document,"Conductor",dataFrame)
            Layer = MapLayers[0]
            Extent = Layer.getExtent(True) # visible extent of layer
            dataFrame.extent = Extent
            arcpy.RefreshActiveView() # redraw the map
            time.sleep(3)
            print "\n\n**** SETTING UP ARCGIS WORK ENVIRONMENT ****\n\n"
            arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = allow_tile_to_overwrite 
            arcpy.env.workspace = tile_workspace
            time.sleep(5)
            print "\n\n**** CREATING TILE PACKAGE FOR MAP " + lyr.datasetName + " ****\n\n"
            arcpy.CreateMapTilePackage_management(mxd_file_name, "ONLINE", lyr.datasetName + ".tpk", "PNG8", "10")
            print "\n\n**** TILE PACKAGE FOR MAP " + lyr.datasetName + " FINISHED ****\n\n"
            time.sleep(6)
            print "\n\n**** MOVING ON TO THE NEXT MAP ****\n\n"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what was causing my issue. I was trying not to create a bunch of waste by avoiding creating a bunch of .mxd files for every feature class I was trying to tile. For some reason when mxd.save is in loop it would mess up my tile packages. So I had to restructure my code and incorporate mxd.saveACopy instead of mxd.save. Here was the previous work flow:

-Open .mxd template
-Swap out "Conductor Layer data source"
-save the .mxd
-Start the tiling process 
-Iterate to the next feature class and repeat the process

The change I had to make was to separate my work flow into two loops that would iterate through feature classes to make .mxd files. Then iterate through the .mxd files to create the .tpk files. The work flow is as follows:

First Loop:
Open .mxd template>>
Swap out Layer data source>>
Save a copy of the .mxd named as the feature class that was used to change the 
  layer's data source>>
Iterate to the next

Second Loop: "Would start after all of the .mxd files were made"
-Open .mxd file>>
Generate .tpk >>
Iterate to the next .mxd and repeate

Below is the code for anyone who might need a tool like this or could use sections of it for their own projects. In order for the code to run create a folder on your desktop, you can name it anything you want. Add in the .py file that contains this code into the new folder. Create a new folder within the already created folder and name it New_Mxd_Files. You will also need to add the .mxd file that you will be using as a template for you .tpk files. Place this .mxd file into the folder you created first. Also add in the file geodatabase that will contain the feature classes you want added to the template .mxd file to generate the .tpk files. The file geodatabase will also go into the folder you created first. Open the .py file and search for the layer called "Conductor" and change that to the layer name you want to change the data source with the feature classes that are contained in the file geodatabase. The "Conductor" layer should be on line 29 within the code. Run the code and it will ask you some questions. All of the answers have to be answered within "". For example: "Yes" or "No". When it asks for the name of the .mxd file and for the name of the file geodatabse just use the name with no file extension. The code will automatically add in the file extensions. For exmaple if your mxd file is named My_MXD_File.mxd you would type "My_MXD_File" same thing goes for the file geodatabase. After all of the questions have been answered it will generate .mxd files and save them into the New_Mxd_Files folder this is also where your .tpk files will be saved.

https://gist.github.com/jmoore3274/7a727950c4bfe00b749353a9c62da306

Answer (score 2):

I also faced this problem when I using **arcpy.CreateMapTilePackage_management** in a MXD which includes some tiff layers. It only tiling one level of detail.

In my case it could be solved by using **Build Pyramids** for your image
(e.g. **arcpy.BatchBuildPyramids_management**).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a note to myself about a similar issue and it says:

CORRECT ORDER OF TILE SERVICE PUBLICATION

- Add raster to ArcMap and set the symbology and other layer properties. Save this LYR file (color, classification, treatment of NoData cells, Display, etc.)
- Locate LYR file in Catalog and right click to **Generate Tile Cache** (this is the same tool as **Manage Tile Cache**) and it does not disclose all options as Manage Tile Cache. To make sure you are creating the right tiles (to be shown at the desired zoom levels), it is best to use **Generate Tile Cache Tiling Scheme (Data Management)** to set the steps correctly. Also pay attention to AGOL maps' zoom level steps, such as the standard scale steps are 1128,2256,4513,9027,18055, so on and so forth (check map service page of the tile).
- Add cache data into ArcMap to view if all shows correctly.
- If all looks OK, first use Export Tile Cache to export cache as TILE_PACKAGE (this is in option in this tool under Export Cache As)
- Then use **Share Package** tool (as you logged in to AGOL) to upload the package.
- Go to AGOL's My Content tab and find the PCK to unpack as Tile Map Service.